# Firebase Analytics Android, nothing is showing in DebugView despite Successful upload

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Why is Firebase Analytics so hard??? I mean here are my logs from ADB... but nothing is coming up in the DebugView. Why is nothing shown in debug view, or even in the RealTime

```
08-30 17:32:18.426 V/FA      (19688): Connecting to remote service
08-30 17:32:25.312 D/FA      (19688): Connected to remote service
08-30 17:32:25.313 V/FA      (19688): Processing queued up service tasks: 1
08-30 17:32:25.333 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Logging event: origin=app,name=AddContact,params=Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=app, ga_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-5856290298640118421}]
08-30 17:32:25.375 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 500
08-30 17:32:25.375 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Unscheduling upload
08-30 17:32:25.378 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Scheduling upload, millis: 500
08-30 17:32:25.379 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Background event processing time, ms: 46
08-30 17:32:25.881 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Unscheduling upload
08-30 17:32:25.886 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Starting upload from DelayedRunnable
08-30 17:32:25.898 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Checking account type status for ad personalization signals
08-30 17:32:25.915 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Saving bundle, size: 586
08-30 17:32:25.964 D/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Uploading events. Elapsed time since last upload attempt (ms): 512
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data: com.vlix.contacts, 646,
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): batch {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):   bundle {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     protocol_version: 1
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     platform: android
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     gmp_version: 42054
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     uploading_gmp_version: 212621
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     dynamite_version: 51
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     config_version: 1630303013946845
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     gmp_app_id: 1:802756057028:android:746c167d718856518c7691
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     admob_app_id:
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     app_id: com.vlix.contacts
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     app_version: 1.0
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     app_version_major: 1
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     firebase_instance_id: efnA2KFVQgeS3N-8wy4oYs
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     app_store: manual_install
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     upload_timestamp_millis: 1630315945887
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     start_timestamp_millis: 1630315938381
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     end_timestamp_millis: 1630315938381
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     previous_bundle_start_timestamp_millis: 1630315800414
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     previous_bundle_end_timestamp_millis: 1630315800414
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     app_instance_id: ac257ea2dd28993b14373cbaf0b722de
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     resettable_device_id: a6a13aad-6762-43b0-ab4c-d6caf5972e3e
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     ds_id: DSID=AAO-7r7J8XMTKN1joLt5psppg-DFJ1xJYYD2YPSNc34ozaR0-8fe6Xffp577Muhyzfm5voEyttyVNpsfyg8oMk7ePpIniMkCTrfsINPBTX4Y3nE0CcBhWV8
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     limited_ad_tracking: false
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     os_version: 10
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     device_model: POCOPHONE F1
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     user_default_language: en-gb
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     time_zone_offset_minutes: 480
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     bundle_sequential_index: 39
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     service_upload: true
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     health_monitor:
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     consent_signals: G1--
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     user_property {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       set_timestamp_millis: 1630308718271
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       name: first_open_time(_fot)
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       string_value:
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       int_value: 1630310400000
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     user_property {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       set_timestamp_millis: 1630308718271
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       name: first_open_after_install(_fi)
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       string_value:
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       int_value: 0
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     user_property {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       set_timestamp_millis: 1630315945897
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       name: lifetime_user_engagement(_lte)
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       string_value:
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       int_value: 1
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     user_property {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       set_timestamp_millis: 1630314084244
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       name: ga_session_number(_sno)
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       string_value:
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       int_value: 1
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     user_property {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       set_timestamp_millis: 1630314084244
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       name: ga_session_id(_sid)
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       string_value:
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       int_value: 1630314084
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     user_property {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       set_timestamp_millis: 1630315945898
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       name: session_user_engagement(_se)
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       string_value:
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       int_value: 0
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     event {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       name: AddContact
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       timestamp_millis: 1630315938381
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       previous_timestamp_millis: 1630315800414
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       param {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):         name: ga_event_origin(_o)
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):         string_value: app
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       param {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):         name: _r
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):         int_value: 1
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       param {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):         name: ga_screen_class(_sc)
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):         string_value: MainActivity
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       param {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):         name: ga_screen_id(_si)
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):         int_value: -5856290298640118421
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       param {
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):         name: _dbg
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):         int_value: 1
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):       }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):     }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265):   }
08-30 17:32:25.974 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): }
08-30 17:32:25.981 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: false, true, false
08-30 17:32:25.983 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Uploading data. size: 602
08-30 17:32:26.162 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3599991
08-30 17:32:26.162 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Unscheduling upload
08-30 17:32:26.165 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Scheduling upload, millis: 3599991
08-30 17:32:26.167 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Successful upload. Got network response. code, size: 204, 0
08-30 17:32:26.174 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Nothing to upload or uploading impossible
08-30 17:32:26.174 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Unscheduling upload
08-30 17:32:26.176 V/FA-SVC  ( 4265): Stopping uploading service(s)
08-30 17:32:30.331 V/FA      (19688): Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Salam! Can you add more details about what tutorial you're trying to follow, and more about what you already did to debug? PS: Firebase analytics sucks because it has so many rules, MS AppCenter is THE best. Are you sure the `google-service.json` file is correct? Did you run this exact command: `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app`? And then did you run these to get verbose logs `adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE`,
`adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE`,
`adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC`?

Comment: Some tools like Microsoft AppCenter already includes Firebase but forcefully disable analytics tracking. You need to actively re-enable it by adding the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml file within the tag: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  ...
  <string name="google_app_id">X:XXXXXXXXXXXX:android:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</string>
</resources>` where that value comes from mobilesdk_app_id value of your json file. Also try to keep your event name characters to all small

Comment: Can you please provide a sample for adding <resources> tag in manifest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It was because I had Microsoft.Analytics nuget installed. Microsoft Analytics (AppCenter Analytics) somehow interfere with Firebase analytics.

Choose one, and definitely Firebase Analyticis is way better from a marketing point of view. You can create funnels, analyze user experience, etc.

Comment: Where do I find Microsoft.Analytics and uninstall it?

Answer (score -1):

You need to connect your device to see events in DebugView
https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Comment: My device is connected.... I am running in debug mode!

Comment: but in your screenshot No Devices Available is written

Comment: Yeah...that's what I'm trying to figure out... it says no devices despite me connecting to one!

Comment: did you tried this "adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app package_name"?